# Zero Set of the Minimum of Brownian Motions

Tags: general-topology, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis, cantor-set

We know that the zero set of a Brownian motion $(B(t))$, $T:=\{s\in [0,1]:B(s)=0\}$, is almost surely homeomorphic to the Cantor set. I would like to prove that the zero set of the minimum the absolute value of $N$ Brownian motions, $S=\{s\in [0,1]:\min_i |B^i(s)|=0\}$, is also homeomorphic to the Cantor set.

My intuition for why this would be true is something along the following lines. $S=\bigcup_{i=1}^N S_i$, where $S_1,...,S_N$ are $N$ i.i.d copies of $T$. Then taking the union, by some scaling argument, $\bigcup S_i$ should also be homeomorphic to the Cantor set. I expect this because $B(t)$ has the same law $N^{-1/2}B(Nt)$, and the prefactor doesn't make a difference to the zero set, so since $B(Nt)$ is covering $N$ times 'more time' it should have a zero set which is like $N$ 'lots of' $T$, which is like $\bigcup S_i$.

This kind of maths is not my speciality so I would appreciate any help in making this arguments rigorous (if they are true!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple topological or metric arguments, namely stability of some properties by finite unions gives the result. The independence of the $N$ Brownian motions is not required here.

Almost surely, $S$ is a closed set with $0$ Lebesgue measure and without isolated points since $S_1,\ldots,S_n$ are closed set with $0$ Lebesgue measure without isolated points. Therefore $S$ has an empty interior.